# Default value if no value is in the scope?

Tags: angularjs

Retreiveing a value like {{cat}} from angular, is there a way to set a value that will output if no value is in the `$scope`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you want to do something like this:

```
<div ng-init="cat = cat || 'Tom Cat'">{{cat}}</div>
```

If you are not looking to initialize but just want to display it:

```
<div>{{cat || "Tom Cat"}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also u can use

```
$scope.cat ||= "Tom Cat"
```

in your controller.